# Split string in to multiple parts in PHP

Tags: php

I'm writing an IRC bot in PHP and trying to split the below notice down in to multiple parts.

```
:irc.server.com NOTICE PHPServ :*** CONNECT: Client connecting on port 6667 (class users): Guest!Guest@127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) [Guest]<br />
```

So far I am using:

```
while(1) {
    while($data = fgets($socket)) {
        echo nl2br($data);
        flush();

        $ex = explode(' ', $data);

        if($ex[0] == "PING"){

            fputs($socket, "PONG ".$ex[1]."\n");

        }

        if($ex[1] == "NOTICE"){
            if($ex[6] == "connecting"){

            $userstring = $ex[12];
            $usernick = strstr($userstring, '!', true);
            $userip = strstr($userstring, '@');

            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

So `$user.nick` is working ok but `$user.ip` includes the @ and the IP address. Why does this include the @ but the nickname doesn't include the !?

Also how can I get `$user.ident` which is between the ! and the @?

Comment: What are you exploding by? If `$ex` is an array of your string exploded as I presume.

Comment: `$user.nick =` is certainly not "working", that's not valid PHP.

Comment: @Ryan Sorry, updated with complete code.

Comment: @user2656114 I didn't get as far as looking at your variable names as I didn't know what you were exploding by. But like deceze said, your variable names are invalid and won't run correctly.

Comment: `$user.nick` did echo the nickname. But still, I removed the `.`.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
$userParts = explode('@', $userstring);
$userip = end($userParts);
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is includes the '@' is because (source: http://php.net/strstr):

> Returns part of haystack string starting from and **including the first
>   occurrence of needle** to the end of haystack.

To solve this you could use substring like this:

```
$userstring = $ex[12];
$exPos = strpos($userstring, '!');
$atPos = strpos($userstring, '@');

$usernick = strstr($userstring, '!', true);
$userip = substr($userstring, $atPos + 1);
$userident = substr($userstring, ($exPos + 1), ($atPos - $exPos) - 1);
```

I left the first strstr because it's easier to read/understand than a substring call.